# render html content in ios push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am able to render rich push notifications using notification extension. My requirement is to render the html content in title or body.

is it possible to render html content in push notifications?

Comment: Do you mean render html content in the collapsed notification view or in the extended state?

Comment: I mean in both the cases

Comment: The collapsed notification doesn't allow any custom UI. For now it will just show text and an optional image. In the expanded notification you can have any `UIView` you want including a `UIWebView` to render web content.